# RequestContext via timer nullpointer exception

Tags: java, primefaces

I got a nullpointer exception when calling requestContext.execute with TimerTask.

generateTimesStep() is started when button is clicked.
After that timer is called every second to update location on map.

The problems is that the execute function is null when called by timer

**GenerateTimeStep class**

```
    public void generateTimeStep() {
    requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.execute("createPoint(" + 1 + "," + lat1 + "," + lng1 + ")");
    RequestContext.setCurrentInstance(requestContext);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Timer called");
            if (lat1 < lat2) {
                lat1 = lat1 + 0.000001;
            }
            if (lng1 < lng2) {
                lng1 = lng1 + 0.000001;
            }
            if (!Objects.equals(lng1, lng2) || !Objects.equals(lat1, lat2)) {
                requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                //if (requestContext != null) {
                   // System.out.println("request aint null");
                    requestContext.execute("updatePoint(" + 1 + "," + lat1 + "," + lng1 + ")"); //NULLPOINTER
               // }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
function createPoint(vIndex,vLat, vLng){
var point = new MQA.Poi({lat: vLat, lng: vLng});
point.setRolloverContent("Indi's Cribbb!!!!");
var icon1 = new MQA.Icon("http://example.com/pictures/Car.png", 50, 29);
    point.setIcon(icon1);
    window.map.addShape(point);
    mycars[vIndex] = point;}

    function updatePoint(vIndex, vLat, vLng)
    {   
var point = mycars[vIndex];   
point.setLatLng({lat:vLat,lng:vLng});
   }
```

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.String to field beans.IndexBean.timer of type java.util.Timer in instance of beans.IndexBean
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1999)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readRemainingObject(StandardSession.java:2078)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1986)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.deserialize(StandardSession.java:1272)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.readSessions(StandardManager.java:555)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.loadSessions(WebModule.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:537)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Info:   Loading application [AutoSysteem] at [/]
Info:   AutoSysteem was successfully deployed in 11.338 milliseconds.
Warning:   Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /
Severe:   Exception in thread "Timer-2"
Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at beans.IndexBean$1.run(IndexBean.java:91)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: Could you paste all the error trace?

Comment: added stack trace. Nullpointer happens after classCastException. But don't think it's caused by that. If you need something more just say so :). Thanks in advance